# Ubuntu Apache Subdomain not Displaying

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, subdomain, directory

Using Ubuntu 18.04

I have my main website `www.example.com`, all the files are hosted in `/var/www/html/` and it works as expected. I would now like to make a new website in a subdomain `www.blog.example.com`.

I created a new dns record for the subdomain on my web host and have confirmed that it's working, when I ping `www.blog.example.com` I see the correct server IP address.

My directory structure looks like this;

- `/var/www/html` (contains all files for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))
- `/var/www/blog.example.com` (contains single index.html file for testing)

I have virtual hosts for each domain, contents are below;

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/rascal.ac.uk>
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/blog.example.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.example.com
    <Directory /var/www/blog.example.com/>
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

There's also `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` looks like this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

All sites are enabled and I have reloaded / restarted apache multiple times.

When I visit `www.example.com` I see my main website, as expected. When I visit `www.blog.example.com` I see my main website also, I should be seeing the contents on my `index.html` file.

If I **disable** `000-default.conf` both urls display the contents of `blog.example.com`, could the issue be in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
ServerName blog.example.com
```

but that's a different name from [www.blog.example.com](http://www.blog.example.com). So Apache doesn't use that VirtualHost. It falls back to the default VirtualHost instead. Adding

```
ServerAlias www.blog.example.com
```

should fix it. See [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias).

Of course these are example names. If that doesn't fix it, please edit your question to show the real hostnames.

Comment: Thanks for this and the explanation!